# Need help getting gulp typescript workflow

Tags: javascript, gulp, ecmascript-6, typescript1.7

I've been steadily improving my JS workflow thanks to gulp. Now that I've got the basics of es6 and typescript down, I'd like to add it to my gulp workflow. I am using Visual Studio Code on a Mac and I am using a tsconfig.json rather than gulp-typescript options.

My gulp workflow should look a bit like:

- take all ts files from src/ts
- compile to es5
- combine to a single file
- use es6 imports/exports pull functions/objects from one module into another.

The goal is to have a single closure wrapped module (revealing module pattern) and all of my classes/functions inside of that module.

My current setup (relevant lines):

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
ts = require('gulp-typescript'),
tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');

gulp.task('ts', function() {
    var tsResult = tsProject.src()
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(ts(tsProject));

    return tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

tsconfig:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "outFile": "build/js/app.js",
    "module": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true
},
"files": [
    "src/ts/file1.ts",
    "src/ts/file2.ts"
]
}
```

I created two simple test ts files:

file1:

```
import {someFunction} from "ajax";

someFunction("Testing");
```

file2:

```
export function someFunction(message: string) {
    let test = `Hello World ${message}`;
    console.log(test);
}
```

So first issue: it produces an app.js in the build/js folder, but it is empty unless I comment out the import statement. Am I misunderstanding how es6 imports work or how maybe typescript works?

Second issue: it creates a new directory structure at root that is basically: Users/username/Documents/JS/Project/ts/files. These files are partially transpiled to es5, retaining the export and import keywords.

I really like typescript and es6 and want to add it to my workflow but so far no online resources have helped me get this build working.

UPDATE:

I just realized I was trying to compile directly to ES5 using es6 modules. Since that won't work, would it be easier to compile to es5 with commonjs modules and then use something like browserify to combine the code?

If I change my tsconfig to:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "outFile": "build/js/app.js",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true
},
"files": [
    "src/ts/file1.ts",
    "src/ts/file2.ts"
]
}
```

That weird full path directory contains the correctly transpiled code but the app.js file is still blank.

UPDATE 2:

I got the weird added directory problem solved by adding `"isolatedModules": false` to my compilerOptions. I changed the module to commonjs as I've decided to use browserify to handle combining modules.

I changed the the gulp.dest to build/js and removed outFile. This has gotten me to the point where I get the output in the correct directory but it adds it to a sub-folder. Basically I want it to output: build/js/files but it outputs build/js/src/ts/files.

UPDATE 3:

I just wanted to add something to the above for anyone else who runs into this problem. The reason I had issues with the modules, is because I was using outFile. outFile does not allow external modules and will output an empty file.